# Swapping Lock On Exterior Door

Tags: doors, exterior, lock

I thought this was simple standard take out the old, plug in the new.  However, I am switching from a Schlage to a GateHouse and the (excuse my lack of terminology) actual "lock", the piece that slides in the cylindrical hole in the side of the door, on my GateHouse is probably 1/2 to 3/4 inch thicker than the "lock" on the Schlage.

Now I have put the Schlage back on, but i want to swap it out.  What do I Need to do in order to make the "lock" hole bigger to fit the new Gatehouse lock?

Comment: Is the gatehouse a round or square type? Retrofitting is tougher than new because you will need to ream the hole out with a larger bit if round or chizzle if square trying to cut with a hole saw usually is tough because there is nothing to keep the bit centered.

Answer (score 2):

buy a cheap set of holesaws. This one is only $8 if you use a 20% off coupon.

https://www.harborfreight.com/1-in-2-12-in-carbon-steel-hole-saw-set-11-pc-68114.html

buy a set that has the correct diameter holesaw.  create a template by drilling the correct diameter into a scrap of 3/4" plywood. attach the plywood template to the door using clamps or screws.  go ahead and drill the new hole in the door.

if it is the large hole on the face of the door, you can prevent splintering by drilling in two steps.  drill the new hole only halfway deep. remount the template on the other side and drill the remainder.

if it is the small hole on the edge of the door, clamp a scraps of 2x4 to door, one to the front and one to the back, then mount the  plywood template by screwing it into the 2x4 scraps.

Answer (score 0):

Buy, borrow, or rent a lockset jig to make it easier to enlarge the hole for the new *latch*. Then use a forstner type bit instead of a spade/paddle bit.

[image]

[image]